# Tools for synchronizing database schema with Oracle, SQL-Server and Netezza databases

Tags: sql-server, oracle, schema, migration, netezza

I'm looking for software tools to move database schema for Oracle, SQL Server and Netezza.  We use Oracle for our ODS, Netezza for our Data Warehouse (for it's bulk loading capabilities) and SQL Server for internal tool development.

When we move data schema from one environment to another, it's all done manually.  This takes a lot of time.  And we use Informatica to move the actual data.  To my knowledge, Informatica cannot move database schema.  What tools can I buy that can move database schema for all three database management systems?

I see Red Gate SQL Compare can move schema.  But it doesn't look like it can handle Oracle or Netezza.  If you don't know one single tool that can be purchased to move schema for all 3 DBMSs, can you give let me know what tools folks recommend for each one?

PS: I didn't see a Stack Exchange [tag] for Netezza.  But I believe Netezza is based on PostGres, so I included that in the tag list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I have used [ErWin](http://erwin.com/) from Computer Associates and [PowerDesigner](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner) to move schema between RDBMSes. It's been many years since then, and I would evaluate their current feature set if I had to pick something today.

Comment: just found "SchemaDiff Multi-DB" ... http://www.datanamic.com/dezign/

Comment: I have used Dezign as well but I never looked at any multi DB features it might have.